# How to efficiently send the length of a message you are about to send in a socket?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

I have a server and a client.
I want the client or the server (depends on who receives the data from the sender) to know what is the exact length of the message that was sent before receiving it.

I first tried getting the sender of the message first send the length of the message with "-" in the end.
After that on the receiver side, there is a while loop that gets the numbers sent from the sender that continues looping until it gets a specific char like "-". After the loop stopped, the receiver converts the string he got to an integer and puts that in the parameter for the length of the message he is gonna receive.

However, is there a better way to send the length of a message other than that while loop or is there a way to get the specific message that got sent over the socket (i.e lets say I sent 2 messages over the socket, and when I receive a message it first receives the first one and then the second one)?

Comment: Did you check out the official Python [Socket Programming HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html)? It lists several means to mark message lengths. Note that "better" depends on your use-case – for example if your data is always (roughly) the same size, sending *no* length but a padded message might be best. Also keep in mind that "socket" is not a specific protocol – iterative reading as describe would not be feasible at all for datagram/UDP sockets. Are you asking about TCP/STREAM in specific?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about TCP sockets (it sounds like you are) then AFAIK the method you described is about as good as it gets.  In particular, the TCP layer doesn't implement any *message-framing* feature, so you have to implement that logic yourself, which is what you are doing.

Note that this doesn't mean your receiver has to `look for a particular char like "-"`.  If you send your message-length field in a fixed-length format (e.g. zero-pad the length-value's ASCII string so that "10" is sent like "0000010", or alternatively send the message-length field as a 32-bit binary value (using e.g. [struct.pack("!i") on the sender and struct.unpack("!i") on the receiver](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html)) then your receiver can just receive a fixed number of bytes to get the message-length, followed by receiving the correct number of message-payload bytes as specified by the length-field's value.